# Retrofit Logging Error

Tags: android

I am authenticating against an API EndPoint using the Password Grant Flow for OAuth2. The library I am using is Retrofit.

I get the following error:

```
D/OkHttp: {"error":"invalid_clientId","error_description":"ClientId should be sent."}
```

I would like to see exactly what API Call I am sending so I can check it for errors.. I have searched the web and found that you need to add a LoggingInterceptor, which I am doing. Still not getting the full API Call..

In my log I get a track of the headers I am sending, as well as the URL, but not the body parameters.. Is there a way to also get the body parameters in the logging?

I would like to see each parameter with its sent value..

The code with provisional credentials can be found at:

https://github.com/NVwingh84/ATTAPITest

Code that I am using is:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private String grant_type = "password";
private String username = "xxxxx";
private String password = "xxxxx";
private String clientId = "xxxxx";
private String client_secret = "xxxxx";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    AccessTokenRequest mytokenrequest =  new AccessTokenRequest(grant_type,username,password,clientId,client_secret);
    sendNetworkRequest(mytokenrequest);
}

public void sendNetworkRequest(AccessTokenRequest accessTokenRequest){

    //create okhttpclientbuilder and set up logging for full logging level "Body"
    OkHttpClient.Builder okhttpclientbuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

    //App will only log if you are in development mode
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG){
        okhttpclientbuilder.addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor);
    }

    Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://api.allthingstalk.io")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(okhttpclientbuilder.build());

    Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();

    AccessTokenClient client = retrofit.create(AccessTokenClient.class);
    Call<AccessTokenRequest> call = client.getAccessToken();
    call.enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "EndPoint Response", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

add below dependency into app level gradle file..

```
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
```

and make separate class for retrofit object define and it is easy to access like below code..

```
public class ApiClient {
private final static String BASE_URL = "https://dog.ceo/api/breed/";

public static ApiClient apiClient;
private Retrofit retrofit = null;

public static ApiClient getInstance() {
    if (apiClient == null) {
        apiClient = new ApiClient();
    }
    return apiClient;
}

//private static Retrofit storeRetrofit = null;

public Retrofit getClient() {
    return getClient(null);
}


private Retrofit getClient(final Context context) {

    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    client.readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    client.writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    client.connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    client.addInterceptor(interceptor);
    client.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request request = chain.request();

            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
    });

    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .client(client.build())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();


    return retrofit;
}
}
```

Comment: Problem still persists, I get the headers and some other information, not the parameters.. If you have the time you can check my code on GitHub.. https://github.com/NVwingh84/ATTAPITest

Comment: Provisional credentials are in there, I can change them up once I have it up and running..